# Securing postMessage() on Cordova

Tags: cordova, iframe, postmessage

My Cordova mobile app uses an iframe to load in a website. I want to send and receive contents over the iframe with `postMessage()`. However, through my testing my mobile app origin is always `localhost:8000` or `file://`. Every other example on this site uses a unique domain and origin (e.g. www.example.com), but my origin is obviously not unique.

How can I secure communication between my mobile app and my website if my origin is `localhost:8000` / `file://`? If for whatever reason I'm not able to, can I use access tokens to validate any communication like shown below?

mobile.app

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
var data = {
  'access_token': 'whatever'
};
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(data, 'localhost:8000');
```

website.com

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (!event.data || !event.data.access_token) {return;}
  // ajax request to validate the token here
});
```

If it helps, the things I'm doing are:

- Detect when the iframe has finished loading. iframe sends back an object. `{'loaded':true}`
- Send an object with a boolean *from* the iframe when the user logs out. `{'logout':true}`
- Send an object with a boolean and an html string *from* the iframe when the user presses  a print button. `{'print':true, 'html':htmlString}`
- Send encrypted payload to the iframe, then waiting for the iframe to return an object. `{'success':true}`

Comment: Wondering why dont you use an InAppBrowser to load website inside the app.

Comment: Because my mobile app uses its own navigation header.

Comment: I guess customised inappbrowser should help you out.

Comment: I looked into it. Short of editing the plugin itself (beyond my expertise and scope), there are no options for that.

Comment: Then you got to take care of the stuffs as mentioned in this link - https://gist.github.com/jedp/3005816

Comment: the official cordova link - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/security/#iframes-and-the-callback-id-mechanism itself suggests to avoid the usage of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

While sending data using postMessage, you can encrypt communication by specifying https://... in the origin url.

Using this kind of procedure is a gate to cross site scripting, you should verify caller and callee on web app and mobile side. More specs about postMessage available here (and useful consideration regarding threats):
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

For authentication, you'll have to put authentication in the data transmitted as you did (with something provided by hand by the user of the phone, otherwise it is not authenticating anything).

To read data, from cordova, you should use an AJAX request targeting a service on the web server.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I cannot set the origin url if it does not match the origin of the mobile app which is always `localhost:8000` or `file://`, that means I cannot put anything starting with `https://` because it won't work.

Comment: I miss something in your data flow... the iframe is the result of an html stream coming from the web server so it should be named, unless cordova hide it under this generic "localhost:8080". In this case, try to target directly the web server service from main javascript when the iframe onload event is triggered.